# Несрабатывающая миграция. Добавление новых столбцов в таблицу. Отображение всех столбцов в интерфейсе

Tags: php, база-данных, laravel, веб-программирование, миграция

Я смотрел видеурок [Laravel 9 и Vue 3 SPA интернет магазин 7. CRUD по пользователям](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yhXHg-A1ORw&list=PLd2_Os8Cj3t9UEjGQHafQB751mf5cwqNv&index=10).
См. с `0:00`-`5:00`.

Есть таблица, поставляемая по умолчанию 
`2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table.php`

```php
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

return new class extends Migration
{
    /**
        * Run the migrations.
        *
        * @return void
        */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
        * Reverse the migrations.
        *
        * @return void
        */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('users');
    }
};
```

Затем создаю следующую миграцию
`2022_09_07_add_surname_patronymic_age_address_gender_to_users_table.php`

```php
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

return new class extends Migration
{
    /**
        * Run the migrations.
        *
        * @return void
        */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->string('surname')->nullable();
            $table->string('patronymic')->nullable();
            $table->integer('age')->nullable();
            $table->string('address')->nullable();
            $table->unsignedSmallInteger('gender')->nullable();
        });
    }

    /**
        * Reverse the migrations.
        *
        * @return void
        */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->dropColumn('gender');
            $table->dropColumn('address');
            $table->dropColumn('age');
            $table->dropColumn('patronymic');
            $table->dropColumn('surname');
        });
    }
};
```

В результате последняя миграция не поменяла таблицу `users` из базы данных
*(должны были добавиться столбцы `surname`, `patronymic`, `age`, `address`, `gender`)*

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И как следствие добавились не все поля в таблицу

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Поле Пол добавилось, потому что сработала ветвь else

```
<td>@if ($user->gender==1) {{"Мужской"}} @else {{"Женский"}} @endif</td>
```

`$user->gender` не было определено, поэтому вывелся в столбце пол Женский и отобразились только те столбцы (`id`, `name` и `email`), которые были определены в первой миграции.

Как добиться добавления новых столбцов в таблицу users и отображения значений всех столбцов (из всех миграций) в интерфейсе?

P.S. В результате `php artisan migrate` получил

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а что вы получили в результате выполнения самой миграции в консоле?

Comment: @МихаилРебров добавил результат выполнения самой миграции в консоле.

Comment: Миграция добавлена верно, вы вероятно путаете создание таблицы с выводом данных из неё - если вы создаете колонки в таблице с типом string да еще nullable, то, очевидно же, в таблице данных для них не будет. Добавьте базовый засев пользователей используя Seederы, либо ставьте для каждой из колонок default() значение  - тогда и при выводе они появятся.